# How long should I wait when I run `docker-compose up`? What should I do to retry?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running docker-compose up for open-ocr

This is my screen for past 15 mins

[image]

And in text form:

```
e4b5185880dc: Pull complete
bb3a20c79671: Pull complete
d180bfcd2661: Pull complete
92bd0cb7f0db: Pull complete
27ca5c22f162: Pull complete
347fcf793eea: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:94dfd2b14c7be479f7db16a9d94374f1510004d3911bb7465a0466b5908ac327
Status: Downloaded newer image for tleyden5iwx/open-ocr:latest
Creating dockercompose_openocr_1
Pulling strokewidthtransform (tleyden5iwx/open-ocr-preprocessor:latest)...
ERROR: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/tleyden5iwx/open-ocr-preprocessor/manifests/latest: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Atleyden5iwx%2Fopen-ocr-preprocessor%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

How long should I continue to wait?

What else can I do to speed up or retry?

Comment: Is your CPU busy? (You should not post image of program output)

Comment: Is my CPU busy? No.

I should not post image of program output. Okay, what should I post then?

Comment: **Text**  of program output ;). If the CPU is idle, I guess it's a network issue (check the system I/O too), if it's network then a timeout should occur soon enough.

Comment: I retried. I got a different error. and i googled around the meta stackoverflow for rules that prohibit the use of screenshot. I couldn't find it. Nevertheless, I posted the text version.

Comment: What is your environment and version of the tools involved? Can you restart your daemon in debug mode (as in https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1194#issuecomment-159049523)

Comment: @KimStacks As for the images : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 -- it's not about prohibition but best practices, hence my "should not" and not "must not".

Comment: Thanks Auzias! I have solved my issue by using a VPN. Something wrong with my network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue in the network. I got around it by using VPN and picking a US VPN server